# Can't set max date on date input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set a min and max date to my date inputs, the min setting is working but for some reason the max date is not. What is the problem here?
I have also tried to use getDate()+90 instead of getMonth()+3.

my inputs:

```js
let today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
let date3m = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getMonth() + 3));
document.getElementsByName("start")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
document.getElementsByName("start")[0].setAttribute('max', date3m)
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div>
    <label for="start">Start Dato:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" name="start" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="end">Slutt Dato:</label>
    <input type="date" id="end" name="end" required>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this? You're using standard DOM functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` and `max` need to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. You're setting `max` to  something like `Sat Nov 13 2021 18:14:51 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`, which doesn't work.

Use `toISOString()` just like you do for `today`.

And `setDate()` should be `setMonth()`.

```js
let today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
let date3m = new Date();
date3m.setMonth(date3m.getMonth() + 3);
date3m = date3m.toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("start")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
document.getElementsByName("start")[0].setAttribute('max', date3m)
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div>
    <label for="start">Start Dato:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" name="start" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="end">Slutt Dato:</label>
    <input type="date" id="end" name="end" required>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to remove the time from `date3m` before setting the input's `max` attribute to it.

```js
let today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
let date3m = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getMonth() + 3)).toISOString().split('T')[0];

document.getElementsByName("start")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
document.getElementsByName("start")[0].setAttribute('max', date3m)
```

```html
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div class="calendar">
  <div>
    <label for="start">Start Dato:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" name="start" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="end">Slutt Dato:</label>
    <input type="date" id="end" name="end" required>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the notice. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `setDate` should be `setMonth`